# Card game with animated and holographic cards

Tags: identify-this-game

I recently remembered a card game that I saw couple years ago, here are the things I (vaguely) remember:

- most of the cards being holographic and animated.
- It came in big plastic container that opened up into a little area to put your cards.
- The little area the container opens to has a little card holder that makes the cards both animated and holographic, it had a see through film.

Comment: We are going to need some more details such as what the game involved.

Comment: As a note we like to identify games so if you can provide more information we can try and help.

Comment: The see through part reminds me of Gloom. But that does not match with the rest of the description.

Comment: Other details that will help.  What shape/colour was the container.  Do you know what was on the cards? People, words, monsters etc?  Most importantly can you remember what you did in the game?  Were the cards fighting each other for example?  The more details you can give the better chance of an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the game after searching for it myself its called [Redakai](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/98203/redakai)

It's on sale on eBay and for clearance in some stores since it wasn't popular

[image]

Comment: The nostalgia hit me like a freight train, this is it! Thanks!